# How to relate matches and 2 teams in an entity relationship

Tags: database-schema, entity-relationship

I understand that the types of relationship used in an ER diagram are

One to One,
One to Many,
Many to One, and
Many to Many

If I am to form a relationship between 'Team' entity and 'Match' entity related by 'plays', where each match is played by two teams. What is the kind of relationship here?

Comment: The four binary relationship types you listed aren't the only relationship types supported by the ER model / ER diagrams. There's also ternary relationships like many-to-many-to-many, many-to-many-to-one, many-to-one-to-one, one-to-one-to-one; and higher (n-ary) relationships. However, many notations that are commonly used for "ER diagrams" don't support all the aspects of the ER model. Chen's notation is one that does.

Answer (score 0):

it is many to many. Because we dont have 2 to 2 relationships in ER diagrams.. therefore when it is more than 1 it is many.